# How to show two data set result together horizontally in BIP report

Tags: dataset, obiee, bi-publisher

I have two data set from different fact tables but in report I have to show both the result set together.
If I am using both the data sets it is appending down after the first dataset table.
Please let me know how can I show both the tables together horizontally.

[Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xFFU.png)

[RTF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4xLN.png)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qer6.png)

Answer (score 0):

Nested Tables.

1. Make a new table in your template; 1 row, two columns.
2. Nest/put one of your tables in the first columns of the new table. Put your other table in the second column of the new table.

If you want, you can adjust the new tables cell margins to different values, including 0, to reduce the space around the nested tables.